# Custom DNS Server with Python

Tags: python-2.7, dns, twisted

I am currently doing some research on [IDN Homograph Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).
I want to create a simple & lightweight DNS-Server, which enables me to catch a question, do something with it and give back custom answers.
I've tried Twisted, but I could not really get my head around it.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the linked code for a mini fake DNS helps you?

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491264-mini-fake-dns-server/